# Passing value to other .m file

Tags: ios4

I'm writing a program wich has 2 .h and 2 .m files, it should pass the value of a PageControl from one to the other. But i just passes me 0. Don't know how to do this, so that i can read the correct value?

Here is som sample code:

```
// SubViewViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ExSubViewViewController;

@interface SubViewViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    .....
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
ExSubViewViewController *exSubViewViewController;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) ExSubViewViewController *exSubViewViewController; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPageControl *pageControl;
.....
@end

//  SubViewViewController.m

#import "ExSubViewViewController.h"
#import "SubViewViewController.h"

@implementation SubViewViewController;

@synthesize scrollView, pageControl, exSubViewViewController;
.....
pageControl.currentPage = page; //page is an integer
.....
@end

//  ExSubViewViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SubViewViewController;

@interface ExSubViewViewController : UIViewController {
SubViewViewController *subViewViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SubViewViewController *subViewViewController;

@end


//  ExSubViewViewController.m

#import "ExSubViewViewController.h"
#import "SubViewViewController.h"

@implementation ExSubViewViewController;

@synthesize subViewViewController;
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    int page = subViewViewController.pageControl.currentPage;

NSLog(@"Side: %d", page);
}
.....
@end
```

Hope this is enough code or else you can just ask again. I have left out unimportant code.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you set `subViewViewController` in your `ExSubViewViewController` init code? And are you sure it's already initialized at the point you use it?

**Edit:** the SubViewController pointer (named subViewViewController) that is a member of ExSubViewController should be initialized. This pointer variable is not magically set to the right value unless you do so, or you make it an IBOutlet and connect it appropriately in Interface Builder.

**Edit 2:** class members are nil-initialized, nothing more. And yes, you can make it an IBOutlet and connect it appropriately in Interface Builder.

Comment: What do you mean by set subViewViewController? I have the class in the .h and i import it in the .m

Comment: Ok, understand. But isn't it initialized when i synthesize it? Correct me if i'm wrong, i'm new to iPhone programming. Should the pointer be connected in IB to the pageControl in the subView.xib? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, i understand that the class members have no info in them. How can i now pass the value from SubViewViewController into it? It should be said that these are to different View, so i could not make a connection in Interface Builder?! or is it just me? The line that says: SubViewViewController *subViewViewController, should it be IBOutlet SubViewViewController *subViewViewController?

Comment: I have still not fund out how to pass the value to another .m fil?